# Exclude categories from product_categories shortcode using slug

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
<div class="categories">[product_categories limit="10" columns="5" orderby="menu_order"]</div>
```

Is it possible to hook into product categories shortcode and filter out specific categories from returning (by slug), like you can with products using `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` hook.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'xaa_remove_category', 50, 3);
function xaa_remove_category( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ){
    if( is_front_page() ){
        
        $query_args['tax_query'] = array(array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
        'field' => 'slug', 
        'terms' => ['custom-category-slug'],
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ));
        
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Like this but for product categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `woocommerce_product_categories` filter hook. try the below code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories', 'exclude_product_category', 10, 1 );
function exclude_product_category( $product_categories ){

    $exclude_category = 'test-2'; // your category slug

    foreach ( $product_categories as $key => $product_cat ) {
        if( $product_cat->slug == $exclude_category ){
            unset( $product_categories[$key] );
        }
    }
    
    return $product_categories;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below shortcode using Show all categories**

`[product_categories]`

**Show all categories** but expect ID = 8

- All category ids: 8, 15, 34, 20, 18, 37, 10
- See, this last version is missing the "8"!

`[product_categories ids="15, 34, 20, 18, 37, 10"]`

Hope you can clear how to exclude category

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).